# Informix LOAD FROM file with header

Tags: csv, informix

I'm using Informix LOAD FROM command to bulk insert data from CSV files to a DB table, like:

```
LOAD FROM "file.csv" DELIMITER ";" INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2, col3)
```

The problem is, the first line of each CSV file contains column headers. Is there any way to tell Informix that the first row shall be ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No; there isn't a way to tell standard Informix [LOAD statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0883.htm) to skip a header line.  Note, too, that it won't remove quotes from around fields in CSV format and otherwise deal with things the way CSV format officially expects (though, since you have semicolon-separated values rather than comma-separated values, it is hard to know which rules are being followed — be leery of the treatment of backslashes too).

You might be able to use the Informix DB-Load utility ([`dbload`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.mig.doc/ids_mig_132.htm)) instead; it depends on whether your data is simply using `;` in place of Informix's default `|` delimiter, or whether you have more of the semantics of CSV such as quotes around fields that need to be removed.  If you want to get exotic, the Informix [High-Performance Loader (HPL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.hpl.doc/hpl.htm) can either handle it natively or be trained to handle it.

Alternatively, you could consider using my<sup>*</sup> [SQLCMD](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL) program (it has been called `sqlcmd` a lot longer than Microsoft's johnny-come-lately of the same name) which allows you to specify:

```
LOAD FROM "file.csv" DELIMITER ";" SKIP 1 INSERT INTO table_name(col1, col2, col3);
```

SQLCMD also has an option FORMAT CSV (amongst other formats) that might, or might not, be relevant.  It handles things like stripping quotes from around fields that the full CSV standard supports.

You'll need to have Informix ClientSDK and a C compiler (and the rest of a C development system) installed to build SQLCMD.

<sup>* *Since SQLCMD is my program because I wrote it, any recommendation to use it is inherently biassed; you were warned.*</sup>

---

You could also consider an 'external table' ([CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_2053.htm)), but I'm not sure it is any better than the LOAD statement either with the formats it supports or with the ability to skip the first row of data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The files I'm consuming don't really follow the standard CSV format, but since they will only contain numbers and a few dates, I'm not worrying about format problems. Anyway, I'll definitely have a look at SQLCMD, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

When I Load CSV files using LOAD FROM into Informix I usually load to a temporary table which is all character columns which I then work with. You just delete the header row. Basically your just putting the whole file into a temp table which is easier to work with.